# What is going on with my transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have a bitcoin transaction of 2500 coming in but it has been pending for 8 hours with no confirmations.....i use coinbase as my wallet and was wondering what could possibly be the problem

Comment: You could try to spend the incoming transaction with a decent fee (Child-Pays-For-Parent, also see the question that this was closed as a duplicate of)